# Add Context Menu command in Atom.io

Tags: contextmenu, bookmarks, atom-editor

I'm trying to add a context menu command to the Atom editor so that I can easily toggle bookmarks.  I added the following to my `config.cson` file:

```
"context-menu":
  "atom-text-editor":
    Bookmark: "bookmarks:toggle-bookmark"
```

I restarted Atom and right-clicked on a line of code, but the context menu hadn't changed.  Is there something else that I have to do?  (I've tried Atom on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14, but neither update the context menu.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your init.coffee file:

```
    atom.contextMenu.add {
    'atom-text-editor': [{
        label: 'Bookmark',
        command: 'my-package:toggle'
    }]
}
```